# Test suites from MTM not running in the expected order

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

We are running automation using xaml builds (automationdeploymenttemplate.xaml) and we were OK with whatever order it was picking the test cases from a particular suite.

After running all the test cases from that suite, it picks the next suite in alphabetical order.

It always follows the suite ordering, but all of sudden It's not following the previous suite order and picking test cases from any suite randomly.

How can we get the suites to run in alphabetical order again?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Is your build process template customized? Did you change your build definition recently? Is there any common in the test cases that the build run?

Comment: TFS version is 15.117.26714.0. Yes build process template is customized and it has 'Lab Process Settings' field which allow to set up the environment, build, deploy and test parameters. No, There is no change in build definitions. But we have daily\weekly windows & MS framework updates run on our VMs. So I am not sure whether is there any new update hampered suite execution order.

Comment: What's the result if you run all your test cases in MTM?

Comment: All of them run (via automation) but due to sequence issue most of them fail. We have set up our test cases in such way that all the pre-requisites TCs put in initial suites and then other TCs. So when pre-reqs do not run and main test cases started running hence they get failed.

Comment: Did you reorder the test suite on TEST tab of TFS web portal?

Comment: I just added a new suite in my current plan via MTM and also arranged that suite alphabetically. I have also changed a very old test plan name , deleted the suite in it and created a new suite. AND yes from that day on wards our suites execution order has been changed.   It seems there is some data integrity issue with TFS database in terms of TC ordering Note: We have noticed that current test case execution is following a consistent order but of course it's not following the suite order (alphabetically).

Comment: Is the test case execution order following the order on TEST tab of TFS web portal? Did you try to re-select the test suite in your build definition?

Comment: No, it's not following the order on Test tab as well. I am seeing the same arrangement of suites on test lab as MTM. I had tried to re-select suites many times and also created a new plan, manually created the new suites with required ordering but still it's not following the expected ordering.

Comment: Since you are using TFS 2017, you may consider migrating to new build system. With VS test task, test suites will order as the TEST tab shows when you select them.

Comment: Thank you Cece. Yes we're moving on vNext builds and there we'll use ordered list to execute test cases.

Comment: Moving to vNext build is a good choice as XAML build is deprecated, you'll enjoy the new build system.